# SKSpriteNode retina images appearing too large

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

`[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"circlequarter-green"];`

`circlequarter-green@2x.png` exists in `Images.xcassets`, but when I try to add the node to the scene, the image appears twice as large as it should. Why isn't `spriteNodeWithImageNamed` respecting the retina image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329477/sprite-atlas-and-2x-images

Comment: Sprites aren't in an atlas directory, and the comments there have no relevance with my problem it seems. I can try converting sprites TO atlas images, but that wouldn't address my problem anyway.